# asp forms authentication

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I've build a login page with users defined in asp.net web administration tool and 
I’m trying to give permissions depending on User Role
I use this code

```
Public Sub mainlogin_Authenticate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs) Handles mainlogin.Authenticate

    If Membership.ValidateUser(mainlogin.UserName, mainlogin.Password) Then
        Dim usrInfo As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(mainlogin.UserName)
        Session("UsrName") = usrInfo.UserName

        If User.IsInRole("Deans") Then
            Session("UsrRole") = "Deans"

        ElseIf User.IsInRole("Rector") Then
            Session("UsrRole") = "Rector"

    End If
```

But the thing is, the User.IsInRole is empty because the User in not yet assigned to the the user who’s logging in.

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config do you have a role manager defined?
ex:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"/>
```

see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647401.aspx
"Additional Considerations"

Comment: Hi Adam, can you assist with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302505/asp-net-authentication