# ASP.NET Authentication

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I have the following a login page where the user enters in their username and password.

With that info, I need to then make sure that they are part of the Admin1 role If so, I like to set a cookie on the user's machine.

With the code I have below  User.InRole it doesn't enter into the if statement. If I uncomment the FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtUserName.Text, true); above it works.
Meaning shouldn't I set the cookie only if the user is part of Admin1 role

I have the following but does not seem to work:

```
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text))
    {

     //   FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtUserName.Text, true);

        if (User.IsInRole("Admin1"))
        {
            // code never reaches here 
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtUserName.Text, true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`User.IsInRole("Admin1")` is false right after validation, because principal object hasn't been attached to the current `HttpContext` yet.

If you really want to use `Context.User`, you need to manually attach principal object.

```
var username = txtUserName.Text;
var password = txtPassword.Text;

if (Membership.ValidateUser(username , password))
{
    var roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(username);
    var identity = new GenericIdentity(username);
    var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, roles);
    Context.User = principal;

    // Now you can use Context.User

    // Basically User.IsInRole("Admin1") is same as roles.Contains("Admin1")
    if (User.IsInRole("Admin1"))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);
    }
}
```

### Updated - Authenticate user using Login Control

Since you are using Membership Provider and Role Provider, I would like to suggest to use Login Control.

Once user is authenticated, you can use LoggedIn event to redirect user to appropiate page.

```
<asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" 
   RenderOuterTable="false" OnLoggedIn="LoginUser_LoggedIn">
   ...
</asp:Login>

protected void LoginUser_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Now we know that user is authenticated
   // Membership user = Membership.GetUser(Login1.Username);
   var roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(Login1.Username);

   if(roles.Contains("Admin1"))
      Response.Redirect("~/Admin/");
   else
      Response.Redirect("~/Users/");       
}
```

Comment: Thanks Win- is what you have the ideal way to handle Authentication based on Role and then setting cookie?

Comment: Normally, Membership Provider will attach Principal to HttpContext on `Application_AuthenticateRequest`; you do not have to do anything. Only reason you are creating Principal by yourself is you want to use `Context.User` right after `ValidateUser`. I do not know the reason why you want to use `Context.User` inside login method, because you could have use `Roles.GetRolesForUser` to get the user's roles.

Comment: Thanks Win. My scenerio is that I am given a username and password and then if the user belongs to Admin1 need to forward him to a page which only allows role of Admin1. How would I use the Application_AuthenticateRequest to simplify. Can you kindly do a small example so I understand. Thanks

Comment: I'm with @Win on this one, simply do var roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(username) and redirect if they contain that role. Either way though you want to set the auth cookie, no?

Comment: @Adam Tuliper - Do I even need to set the cookie. I need the user to go to a page that is restricted to only Admin1 (allow role = "Admin1"). Is there anyway I can do without cookies

Comment: @Win - Thanks for your answer. So I do not need to set any cookies, correct? Meaning if Admin page requires Admin1 role(allow role = "Admin1" will the above still work?

Comment: You still need to set auth cookie. Without it, membership provider won't work (UseUri has some issues). If you use Login control, you do not need to set auth cookie explicitly. Login control will do it for you.

Comment: yes, still need to set the cookie otherwise what's to stop someone from just linking to that page directly?